# Rest Plugin or URI to display all the rest Services or End points info

Tags: java, rest, jmeter, jax-rs

I am working on a project which compromises JAX-RS API. They have plenty of web services defined and i need to profile it through J Meter. Can we have any tool or Rest URL which provides all the services and its definitions

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using? If you're using Jersey, then there are WADL endpoints for every API. You can get the root document at http://projectroot/application.wadl. with a GET. Also every ending has it's own WADL by using an OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that your application developers have implemented [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) documentation via i.e. [Swagger-Core JAX-RS](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X), if this is the case you should have a special documentation endpoint listing all URLs, methods, examples, etc.

If this is the case you can even use [Taurus automation framework](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) which comes with [Swagger to YAML converter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Swagger/) so you can go use this for building your test plan like:

```
 Swagger -> Taurus YAML -> JMeter JMX
```

Comment: We used Rest API to build JAX-rs